# Cracks on Decking

Tags: deck, decking

I just moved into a first-floor apartment with a small wood deck in the front, and just last week I applied two layers of teak oil coating. Before that, I cleaned and brushed it  with a special wood deck cleaner liquid.

Once the oil was absorbed by the wood, I realized that some parts of the deck look a bit cracked, and it seems that the oil was not absorbed at those area.

Is there anything that I can do to fix these cracks?

[image]

Comment: I see normal deck wood.  It's going to have small "cracks" and crevices.  What about them bothers you? Is it rough on your feet?

Comment: First it's the color that bothers me, and also as you said it's rough on the feet. But if it looks normal, then I can let it be.

Comment: If the color bothers you, can you use a deck stain rather than a clear oil?  They have natural looking semi-transparent stains.